# Jade Agent using command lines

Tags: agents-jade

I am new to Java Agent DEvelopment Framework for developing Agents.

I used to work with Jade using Eclipse, I've created some agents I converted my file to .jar format. But now I want to test my .jar file by creating multiple agents.

How can I create one or multiple Jade agents using a command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the [tutorials](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html) before asking such questions. Visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read about how to ask good questions.

But nevertheless,To create an agent using command the command line use:

```
java -cp lib\jade.jar;classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

java jade.Boot -agents "a:agents.AgentClass;b:agents.AgentClass".

Note that the classpath includes JADE classes (lib\jade.jar) and the previously compiled classes of the examples (classes). Note also that the value of the -agents option takes the form:

```
 <agent-local-name>:<fully-qualified-agent-class>
```

Using JADE terminology, this is called an "Agent Specifier". More than one agent can be started by just typing several agent specifiers separated by a semicolon (';') as in the example below:

```
 java -cp lib\jade.jar;classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent;ping2:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to the website. Thank you for the link and for your answer.

Comment: It looks like Jade site changed to HTTPS only, so the tutorial link is https://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of your personal workflow it is probably not very comfortable to build the jar file each time you want to test your agents. The better way for debugging is to use the eclipse debug capabilities.

For this, place the jade.jar (and other required libraries) in your eclipse project. Further, configure the Java project to include these libraries in your project. After this you should be able to configure a debug configuration, where ***jade.Boot*** should be the main class, while the further Jade options (for agents or services) can be placed in the start argument tab (hope this rough description is enough).